# Accessing static method using null object

Tags: java, oop

The below code is getting compiled without any errors inspite of accessing the method `dir` from a null object `rt`, whereas i was expected to get `nullpointerexception`. **Why?**

When i removed the static keyword for **dir** method, i got the null pointer exception, so is there any exception for static methods?

```
public class root{

  private root() {}

   final public static void dir(int a)
    {
      System.out.print("Output: "+a);
    }
  }

public class plan{

  public root rt=null;

  public void plot(){ 
       rt.dir(1); //Calling a static method using null object
    }

  public void static main(String[] args){
     plan p1=new plan();
     p1.plot();
 }
}
```

Comment: first its not `Public` its `public`

Comment: A static method doesn't use the object as it's static. It just these the type of the reference known at compile time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Static methods are not linked with objects. Those are class methods. When you call `rt.dir(1)`, JVM replaces it with `Root.dir(1)`.

It's the instance that can be null and can cause NPE, but not the classes. This is why you cannot see any `NullPointerException` here.

Answer (score -1):

If you wish to call static method of another class then you have to write class name while calling static method

You have to use `root.dir(1);`

Comment: Its a good practice to use ClassName, but it is not *mandatory* to use ClassName. He can use an instance of a class to access static members (check his question)